# Creating and load to Postgres Partitioned table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to read XML file(s) in Python, parse them, extract required fields and insert the extracted data into a Postgres table. I am new to Python and Postgres. So was hoping if someone could  please clarify some questions I have in my mind.

The requirement is that there will be 2 target tables in Postgres for every XML file (of a certain business entity e.g. customers, product etc) that should be received and read on a particular day - CURRENT and HISTORY.

The CURRENT table (e.g. CUST_CURR) is supposed to hold the latest data received for a particular run (current day file) on that particular day and HISTORY table (CUST_HIST) will contain the history of all the data received till the previous run - i.e just keep on appending the records for every run into the HIST table.

However, the requirement is to make the HIST table a PARTITIONED table (to improve query response time by partition-pruning) based on the current process run date. In other words, during a particular run, the CURR table needs to be **truncated** and loaded with the day's extracted records, and the records already existing in the CURR table should be copied/inserted/appended  into the HIST table in a **NEW** Partition (of the HIST table) based on the run date.

Now, when I searched the internet to know more about Postgres PARTITION-ing tables, it appears that to create NEW partitions, new tables need to be created **manually** (with a different name) every time representing that partition [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html)?? The example shows a `CREATE TABLE` statement for creating a partition!!

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_HIST_20220630 PARTITION OF CUST_CURRENT
FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-02-01') TO ('2006-03-01')
```

I am sure I have misinterpreted this but can anyone please correct me and help me clear the confusion.

So if anyone has to query the HIST table with the run-date filter (assuming that the partitions are created on the run_date column), the user has to query that particular (sub)table (something like `SELECT * FROM CUST_HIST_20220630 WHERE run_dt >= '2022-05-31'`) instead of the main partitioned table (`SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_HIST`) ?

In other RDBMS's (Oracle, Teradata etc) the partitions are created automatically when the data is loaded and they remain part of the same table. When a user queries the table based on the partitioned column, the DB optimizer engine understands this and effectively prunes the unnecessary partitions and reads only the required partition(s), thereby highly increasing response time.

Request someone to please clear my confusion. Is there a way to automate partition creation while loading data to Postgres table by using Python (psycopg2) ? I am new to Postgres and Python so please forgive my naivety.

Comment: The documentation page is pretty clear and answers your question, which boils down to "do I need to create partitions myself, or can they be created automatically?". Since there is no mechanism defined to create them automatically (and what parameters should it be using to begin with?), the answer is that you do indeed need to come up with a way to create them yourself. You could still do that "automatically", you just can't get the DBMS to do it for you. That makes sense, after all if it could do that: why wouldn't it always do it?

Comment: However, were you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642326/automatic-partitioning-by-day-postgresql

Comment: @Grismar - thanks for your response.. that information is really helpful. I guess I just have to generate a string as a partition creation syntax statement in my Python script like `create table my_tab_<rundt>PARTITION OF CUST_HIST ...` so on and execute that statement just after the data has been loaded to the main partitioned table - Of course the name of the partition needs to be generated by concatenating the table name with the sys_date and place it in the create statement string before executing it from within the script - That works, right ?

Comment: If you're partitioning by day, and it won't be a problem for your program logic that some dates don't have associated partitions (both of which can easily be true, or false, depending on what your applications actually need to do) , then yes that would work. The reason the answer is "it depends" is the same reason it is built this way in the first place - PostgreSQL isn't opinionated on how you should partition your data, because it trusts that you know what is best. Since you're working with daily data and didn't mention creating any data for other days, yes probably in this case.

Comment: @Grismar - thanks for your reply. I will be getting daily XML files to be ingested and dumped to Postgres. The incoming data for any particular day will be inserted to a new partition whose name will contain the current date, something like - "CUST_HIST_20220705" etc. But I didn't understand your statement that some dates don't have associated partitions. Could you please clarify. Also, in this context which partitioning type should be appropriate for daily partition creation? Could you please mention the statement to be used. (Sorry new to Postgres). I Appreciate your help !

Comment: I was suggesting that you may have days where no data is coming in (technical issues or business parameters) and your application logic might generate data that would go into the partition for that day regardless (aggregates, historic backfilling, etc.) - so, if you create a partition only when you receive data, you need to be sure the application logic won't require partitions to be present for days you did not receive data on. It's quite possible that's not an issue for you, in which case you're good.

Comment: @Grismar - thanks for your reply. Final question - which partitioning scheme should I use in this use-case for storing daily data in separate partitions ? Will it be possible for you to give an example statement please, e.g `CREATE TABLE cust_hist_2022_07_02 
PARTITION OF cust_hist FOR VALUES FROM (‘2022–07–02’) TO (‘2020–07–02’);`? Will it work if I keep both the values in the `FROM` clause as the same (current date) as shown in the example above ?

Comment: You should read the documentation more carefully; early on it states "Each range's bounds are understood as being inclusive at the lower end and exclusive at the upper end." - as the examples in the rest show, you would thus use `FROM (‘2022–07–02’) TO (‘2020–07–03’)`. In general, programming requires you to fully (or at a minimum sufficiently) understand the code you're writing - if you have to come to StackOverflow for every edit, you won't get a lot of work done and whoever should really get your job is apparently wasting their time on SO :). Try first, ask here if confused by results.